# Split array into another array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, split

I have a string array like this:

```
string[] Array = new string[3] {"Man(21)", "Woman(33)", "Baby(4)"};
```

Now I want to split this array into this scheme:

```
Array = new string[6] {"Man", "21", "Woman", "33", "Baby", "4"};
```

Anybody have idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var result = Array.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[]
    {
        '(', ')'
    }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from str in Array
let items = str.Split('(')
from item in items
select item.Replace(")", string.Empty);
```

Comment: @downvoter: Why a downvote? This also produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to regular expressions:

```
    var pattern  = @"(?<person>\w+)\((?<age>\d+)\)";
    var Array = new string[3] { "Man(21)", "Woman(33)", "Baby(4)" };
    Array = Array.SelectMany(item =>
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(item, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var person = match.Groups["person"].Value;
        var age = match.Groups["age"].Value;
        return new List<string>{person, age};
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case you might find it more useful to output a list of objects with `Name` and `Age` properties, or a dictionary. Here is an example of the former:

```
        string[] arr = new[] { "Man(21)", "Woman(33)", "Baby(4)", /* test case */ "NoAge" };
        var result = arr.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(r => new
        {
            Name = r.First(),
            Age = r.Skip(1).SingleOrDefault()
        }).ToList();
```

The result is:

> Name  Age
>
> Man   21
>
> Woman 33
>
> Baby  4
>
> NoAge null

Credit to dotctor for the `Split` command.

Comment: what we need to do if we don't want to have result with this scheme: _"Name=Man,Age=21"_ and just see _"Man,21"_

Comment: I used this code instead of yours:
 `var result = arr.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(r => new[]
        {
           r.First(),
           r.Skip(1).SingleOrDefault()
        }).ToList();`
But get a 2 dimension var.